# Wheel built with MSVC Cython extension cannot find module

Tags: python, cython, python-wheel

I'm attempting to switch from a GNU + mingwpy to an MSVC toolchain to build my wheel, which includes a Cython wrapper around a binary.

I've built the external DLL with an MSVC toolchain in Appveyor, and, also in Appveyor, I've got the wheel build step [working](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/urschrei/simplification/build/1.0.46/job/q0xao75epiqd8u6s#L95). After the build step completes, I'm testing by doing the following:

- installing and activating a clean virtualenv
- installing dependencies
- installing the wheel I just built
- running `nosetests wheelname`

However, this is now failing:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named cutil)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "C:\projects\simplification\simplification\test\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    from simplification.cutil import simplify_coords as csimplify_coords
ImportError: No module named cutil
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[see full traceback](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/urschrei/simplification/build/1.0.45/job/f7nd7pq8i3wae6u7#L213)

Running `dumpbin /dependents` on `cutil.pyd` seems to show what I expected:

```
Dump of file simplification/cutil.pyd
File Type: DLL
  Image has the following dependencies:
    rdp.dll
    python27.dll
    MSVCR90.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
  Summary
        4000 .data
        2000 .rdata
        3000 .reloc
       12000 .text
```

Where `rdp.dll` is the external binary I'm wrapping with Cython.
What's going wrong here?

**Update**: My module can also import the binary using `Ctypes`, and when I disable the Cython-specific imports and tests in my test script, everything works. So I know my external binary is OK. I'm still confused as to *why* the import is failing, especially as the Cython build step of `cutil.pyd` completes, and dumpbin says it's looking for its `rdp.dll` dependency in the right place (i.e. in the same directory).

**Update 2**: Running `dumpbin` on `cutil.pyd` that's been built with a GNU toolchain gives the following:

```
Dump of file simplification/cutil.pyd
File Type: DLL
  Image has the following dependencies:
    msvcr90.dll
    python27.dll
    KERNEL32.dll
    USER32.dll
    rdp.dll
  Summary
        1000 .CRT
        1000 .bss
        3000 .data
        1000 .edata
        2000 .idata
        1000 .pdata
        4000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       1E000 .text
        1000 .tls
        1000 .xdata
```

But I have no idea whether the dependency order is significant or whether the metadata in the `Summary` section matters

Comment: Just for clarification: it works with GNU + mingwpy?

Comment: @DavidW yes, worked perfectly before I switched the binary and the Wheel build toolchains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the virtualenv installed by Conda. I have no idea how to fix it, so I stopped using a virtualenv installed by conda.